# Can the Cartesian Product of a set be in the power set of the original set?

Tags: set-theory

Consider a nonempty set $A$. Is it possible for $A\times A \subseteq A$?

I'm fairly certain that this can't be done for a finite set $A$, but what about a set with infinitely many elements? I have a hunch that one could say $a_i, a_j\in A$ implies that $(a_i , a_j)$ would need to also be in $A$, although then so would a Cartesian product with $(a_i,a_j)$ in at least one of its entries. Does anyone know the overall answer to this?
Note: I know very little set theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. There are many examples but I'd argue the best example in a number of ways is $V_\omega$.

$V_\omega$ is the $\omega$th level of the cumulative hierarchy:

- $V_0=\emptyset$,
- $V_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} V_\alpha$ for $\lambda$ limit, and
- $V_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal{P}(V_\alpha)$.

It consists of the *hereditarily finite* sets. You know what it means for a set to be finite; well, a set is *hereditarily* finite if

- it is finite;
- all its elements are finite;
- all its elements' elements are finite;
- and so on.

It's not hard to show that if $X$ and $Y$ are hereditarily finite, so is $(X, Y)$. Hence, $V_\omega\supseteq V_\omega\times V_\omega$.

---

More elementarily, you can think of the set $K$ defined as follows:

- Let $K_0$ be any fixed set to start with.
- Let $K_{n+1}=K_n\cup(K_n\times K_n)$.
- Let $K=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} K_n$.

This is essentially the same picture as $V_\omega$, but it might be easier to visualize first.

---

That said, there *is* an example of a finite set satisfying your property! HINT: what's the most annoying set you can think of? :P

Comment: Love your hint for the finite case.

Comment: If we are thinking of a finite set, the I would imagine that the empty set is the "annoying" example.

Comment: Lol at the last line

Comment: @user328442 That's the one! Do you see why $\emptyset\times \emptyset=\emptyset$?

Comment: Maybe. The empty set contains no elements and so there would be no possible entries for its Cartesian product, making it empty as well.

Comment: @user328442 That's exactly it. Note that the powerset of the emptyset is **not** empty, by contrast. Now, a good exercise: can you show that no finite **nonempty** set $A$ satisfies $A\times A\subseteq A$? (This is harder than it may seem at first; you'll need the [axiom of foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).)

Comment: The power set would then have only one element then, right? Namely, the empty set would be the one element.

Comment: @user328442 That's exactly right.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I think OP realized that the empty set was an example; the question specifically says: "Consider a nonempty set $A.$"

Comment: @MitchellSpector That's possible. I assumed that was the statement of an exercise, and the OP might reasonably not have noticed that "nonempty" was necessary there.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, I can see that.

Answer (score 1):

Noah gave a good answer, which is probably the desired answer, but let me add something to it.

There is no mathematical reason to choose Kuratowski's encoding of ordered pairs ($(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$, and of course there are reasons to choose it: e.g. simplicity), and we can practically choose any encoding. For example, we can explicitly require that $\varnothing$ codes the ordered pair $(\varnothing,\varnothing)$, in which case $\{\varnothing\}\times\{\varnothing\}=\{\varnothing\}$.

But nevertheless, starting with any set $X$ and defining by induction: $A_0=X$; $A_{n+1}=(A_n\times A_n)\cup A_n$; then taking $A=\bigcup\{A_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ will give us a set $A$ such that $A\times A\subseteq A$. And depending on your choice of coding, perhaps even equals to it.